# filling nested arrays in python

Tags: python, list, nested

My task is to make nested arrays with coordinates of cities. I try to write the code but it is not working. Can you help me, please ?

```
i = 0
cities = []
count_of_cities = int(input("How many cities do you want?"))
while i < count_of_cities:
   x = 0
   coordinate_x = int(input("Coordinate x for city is: "))
   coordinate_y = int(input("Coordinate y for city is: "))
   cities[i][x].append(coordinate_x)
   x += 1
   cities[i][x].append(coordinate_y)
   i += 1
print(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in:

```
cities[i][x].append(coordinate_x)
```

In the first iteration for example, you are trying to append to `cities[0][0]` but it doesn't exist at that point (`IndexError` should be thrown) because the list `cities` is empty.
I would suggest you to do:

```
i = 0
cities = []
count_of_cities = int(input("How many cities do you want?"))
while i < count_of_cities:
   coordinate_x = int(input("Coordinate x for city is: "))
   coordinate_y = int(input("Coordinate y for city is: "))
   cities.append([coordinate_x, coordinate_y])
   i += 1
print(cities)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just append the list to the cities and use for loop is better

```
cities = []
count_of_cities = int(input("How many cities do you want?"))
for _ in range(count_of_cities):
   coordinate_x = int(input("Coordinate x for city is: "))
   coordinate_y = int(input("Coordinate y for city is: "))
   cities.append([coordinate_x, coordinate_y])


print(cities)

How many cities do you want?2
Coordinate x for city is: 2
Coordinate y for city is: 2
Coordinate x for city is: 3
Coordinate y for city is: 3
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```